# closing the port after joining thread or before joining the thread?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, serial-port

i want to get signal from port and I used these functions for receiving data,but I sometimes get this exception on line thread.join() :

System.IO.IOException was unhandled

Message="The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

when I insert a breakpoint and debug it, it goes correct until on line thread.join() and the UI then is stopped and nothings occurs.

also when I run my program in release mode it works correctly but the problem is with debug mode,what is goes wrong and how I can solve this problem?

thnx.

```
    public SignalReader()
    {
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMain));
    }
    public void Start(string portName, int rate)
    {
        Stop();
        try
        {
            port = new SerialPort(portName, rate);
            port.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            ;
        }
        thread.Start();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {

        try
        {
            if (port != null)
            {
                if (port.IsOpen) port.Close();
                if (thread.IsAlive) thread.Join();
                port.Dispose();
                port = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("4:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

when i swap the order of closing the port and joining the thread:

```
...
thread.Join();
port.Close();
...
```

the same story exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are jerking the floor mat, closing the port *while it is being used*.  Most typically in a SerialPort.Read() call.  So, yes, that call is going to fail, there's no floor mat anymore.  What's missing is a catch block that catches that exception and lets the thread end gracefully.  And complete the Join() call.

It is not entirely unusual to do this, as long as you can make sure that the thread is actually blocking on such a Read call.  That's not usually very hard to guarantee.  But certainly fret about not getting that exception in the Release build, that's not normal.  Use the debugger's Debug + Window + Threads to see what's going on in that worker thread.

So just add the required try/catch to fix your problem.  Using the SerialPort.DataReceived event is an entirely different approach.  Not cleaning up at all, just setting the thread's IsBackground property to true so it automatically dies when the program terminates is also a quite acceptable solution.

Comment: I used thread.abort() instead of thread.join and the problem have been solved. is there any difference between using them?(my program only shows some signal coming from port and does not do important analysing on data)

Comment: The last sentence of my answer addresses that.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is because of that Stop() you are using in:

```
public void Start(string portName, int rate)
    {
        Stop();
        try
        {
            port = new SerialPort(portName, rate);
            port.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            ;
        }
        thread.Start();
    }
```

The app is doing something already and when you call this it closes a port is being in use somewhere.

Try removing it and you will get an exception in the `Start` method if the port is not closed. It will give you a better idea where this error comes from. Also could you paste the part of the code where you are using these methods?

Comment: when I use Start method the port is null and as you can see i check to see if the port is null(i use it to make Start act as Restart):                     try
        {
            if (port != null)
            {
                if (port.IsOpen) port.Close();
                if (thread.IsAlive) thread.Join();
                port.Dispose();
                port = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("4:" + ex.ToString());
        }

Comment: this is ThreadMain method:
        public void ThreadMain()
        {
            while (port.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {    
                    var b1 = port.ReadByte();
     //read 4 byte and do some work on it
    }
   }
   if(dataBytes.IsValid)
   DataReceive.Invoke(dataBytes)
  }